# TypeScript type error message Extract<keyof R, string>' cannot be used to index type

Tags: typescript, types, typeerror

My problem is that in my **TypeScript **code, I get the error:

`Type 'Extract<keyof R, string>' cannot be used to index type 'T'.`

This is my code:

```
function mergeObjects<T extends object, R extends object>(obj1: T, obj2: R): object {
  const copy: T = { ...obj1 };

  for (const key in obj2) {
    if (!copy.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      copy[key] = obj2[key]; // Error in this line.
    }
  }

  return copy;
}
```

And here is a task:

Write the mergeObjects function, which accepts 2 objects of types T and R (use generic) and returns a new object with all the properties of the first object and those properties of the second that are not in the first.
Example:

```
const user = {
  name: 'Harry',
  surname: 'Potter',
};

const robot = {
  name: 'Cleaner',
  version: 12,
  wheels: 3,
};

mergeObjects(user, robot) === {
  name: 'Harry',
  surname: 'Potter',
  version: 12,
  wheels: 3,
}
```

Comment: You could try to deal with that error, but I'm confused why you're spreading one object and then copying the other piece by piece.  Why not spread both like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9jZMm)?  This seems like a strange example; could you [edit] so that there is actually a motivation for dealing with the error?

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that. This solution is incorrect.
[LOG]: {
  "name": "Cleaner",
  "surname": "Potter",
  "version": 12,
  "wheels": 3
}

Comment: Okay, so spread the other order then like `{...obj2, ...obj1}`. I'm still not seeing a reason for trying to convince the compiler to index into `T` with `keyof R`.  Maybe you could [edit] to actually motivate such a thing?

Comment: Thank you. I understood what you meant and it worked.

Comment: Sure, but that's not answering the question you're asking.  Could you [edit] to either ask your existing question with a better example *or* just ask how to accomplish the task without asking about an error?  Right now the question seems like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).